# Prevent infinite product from trying to evaluate?

Tags: performance-tuning, evaluation

Consider an expression involving several infinite and non-infinite products, like

```
Product[Product[1 - q^(2 + i)*t^(3 - i - j)*x, {i, 0, Infinity}]/Product[1 - q^(2 + i)*t^(2 - i - j)*x, {i, 0, Infinity}], {j, 2 + m2, m1}, {i, 1 + m2, -1 + j}]
```

When I first type in this input and hit enter, Mathematica tries to evaluate the products and it is taking a lot of time until it finally recognizes that this product cannot be evaluated and gives back the original input. Since I do not expect any of my input of the above type to evaluate directly to some closed form, I would like to prevent Mathematica from trying to find a closed form result and just store the input as is. Is there a command to do that? Note that functions like `Hold[]` do not work for me, since I still would like to proceed to work with the input as usual. Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: `Inactivate`...?

Comment: Thank you, this is a useful suggestion! Also, I realized that there are some repeating product indices in the above, which makes the expression effectively meaningless. Fixing the indices makes the "evaluation attempt" much faster, so that it is less of an issue.

Comment: But you might be wrong, and the infinite product *can* be evaluated.  Why would you ever want to preclude that possibility?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Essentially, I am interested in a limit `q->1` of the above anyways. So I first define the general thing, then plan to reduce it in the limit and then want to see what the product evaluates to. I assume the limiting case will evaluate more easily, and that is all I need to find.

Comment: @Kagaratsch:  I urge you to ask the *actual* question you want answered rather than a partial one you think will help you on the way.  That way we can help you better and see opportunities that you might otherwise miss.

Comment: OK, I will try to do that in the future!